# Where is Walt's money?

Tags: breaking-bad

So, *Breaking Bad* has finished.

> In the final episode Walt killed Jack, when he started to talk about money.

But where is Walt's money, which Jack has stolen?

Comment: Probably recovered by the DEA or any other agency that got to the crime scene....

Answer (score 18):

Does it really matter? The police are probably going to find it and confiscate if it's on the meth lab compound. Anyway, these guys must have sold some meth by then and they have more than the amount they stole from Walt. But now that nobody from the crew is alive to tell anyone where they hid the money, it doesn't really matter. It might even be buried somewhere in the desert like in "To'hajiilee," in which case it will slowly fade away inside the container.

Comment: Money may be the subject for episodes about, eg. Saul Goodman.

Comment: AFAIK "Better Call Saul" is the prequel to Breaking Bad, which means this money didn't exist in its timeline. Says [right here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul): `The series will be a prequel about Saul's life before he became Walter White's lawyer.`

Comment: re "better call saul" they are toying with the idea of making the series a prequel, sidequel and sequal to breaking bad , multi points along the timeline

Comment: @howler I really don't expect that at some point Saul will somehow end up with all that money. But we'll see that when the series goes live.

Comment: I do love the idea that better-call-saul will act as both a prequel and sequel. That's a neat spin on things.

Answer (score 8):

Another "it doesn't matter" answer, to accompany the excellent ones already written.

The key thing for me is that this action demonstrates that finally Walt doesn't care about the money.  Its the first time in the entire series that Walt doesn't care about maximizing his return.  Even back in Season 2 when they were selling small quantities via Badger and Skinny Pete, Walt got upset when his cut was $1k light when Skinny Pete was robbed.

There could be several reasons why he doesn't care - he's been injured and knows he is likely to die.  However I think he went into this situation for two main reasons:

- Revenge.  Jack & Todd stole 80% of his money and killed Hank and Steve.  It was this action that finally destroyed Walt's chance to simply return to his family.
- To protect his family from being threatened by Jack & Todd

I think he knew it was risky and possibly might result in his death - but he had to do as much damage as possible to Jack and his crew.

He also clearly has paternal feelings towards Jesse, and when he sees what they've done to him this must also make him angry.  When faced with a choice of killing Jack and taking his revenge or possibly retrieving his cash - there is no choice as far as he is concerned.

Comment: There's no way he could retrieve the cash.  He's been shot and he knows it.  That's why the cash doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter. Walt had the option of finding out where the money was, but he didn't need it. He ensured that his son would get nearly $10 million in less than a year, which he'd likely use to help out his sister and mother (and probably Marie as well), so Walt didn't need the rest of the money anymore, which is why he shot Jack as Jack started to try and talk his way out of the situation.

Answer (score 3):

It's never explicitly answered, within the series.

My expectation would be that, having found the meth lab, the authorities would then leave no stone unturned in pursuit of their money.  Whether it was earned from Jack & his crew cooking/dealing meth or not, would've made little difference.  Living people can contest the seizure, but dead men don't talk.

Given they were not rocket scientists, the money probably would not have remained hidden for long under such intense searching.

Following that line of reasoning, the government found & confiscated the remainder of the 6 barrels of money.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering the question which was asked**: Probably buried at another desert location known only to Jack and the neo-Nazis who where then murdered by Walt. The money will never be found and it may eventually become part of Albuquerque are lore as a "buried treasure." The neo-Nazis would have dry foolish to have buried the money at the same site where they were also still cooking meth.

Or it may be forgotten as Walt is also dead, Jesse and Saul are on the run and Huell and Kuby are probably doing the same. The main characters of the series are all also deceased or distracted and they will likely have forgotten that the money ever existed.

Comment: New series idea ala Better Call Saul... Badger and Skinny Pete: Treasure Hunters!